# why do I get different results with the same conditions in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, signed

I was stuck when I was trying to use a `for` loop to solve a problem.

Here's my simplified code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(2333);
    int n = 10, m = 10;
    for(int i=0; i< -1; i++)
        m--;
    std::cout<<m<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<a.size()-2; j++)
        n--;
    std::cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently, `a.size() = 1` so these two end conditions should be the same. However, when I ran my code on Xcode 9.4.1 I got unexpected as it turned out that `m = 10` 
 and `n = 11`. And I found that the time it took to get the value of `n` is much longer than `m`.

Why would I get such a result? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `a.size() - 2` would result in -1 if the `a.size()` were a signed type. Since `a.size()` is an unsigned type, `a.size() - 2` results in a very large positive number. Example https://ideone.com/d2azlC.

Comment: Then could you please tell me why would it result in such a large positive number and why n merely equals 11?@RSahu

Comment: I'll let somebody do the explaining. I am afraid I don't have all the pieces straight  in my mind.

Comment: The first step when you encounter a surprising result such as this is to examine your assumptions. For instance, adding `std::cout << a.size() - 2 <<endl;` in order to verify that it really is `-1`. Then you can start figuring why it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `size()` is `std::size_t`, which is an unsigned integral type. This means that it can only represent non-negative numbers, and if you do an operation that results in a negative number, it will wrap around to the largest possible value like in modular arithmetic.

Here, `2 - 1` is -1, which wraps to `2^32 - 1` on a 32-bit system. When you try to subtract `2^32 - 1` from 10, you cause a signed integer underflow since the minimum value of a 32-bit integer is `-2^31`. Signed integer overflow/underflow is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so anything can happen.

In this case, it seems like the underflow wrapped around to the maximum value. So the result would be `10 - (2^32 - 1) + 2^32`, which is 11. We add `2^32` to simulate the underflow wrapping around. In other words, after the `2^31 + 10`th iteration of the loop, `n` is the minimum possible value in a 32-bit integer. The next iteration causes the wrap around, so `n` is now `2^31 - 1`. Then, the remaining `2^31 - 12` iterations decrease `n` to 11.

Again, signed integer overflow/underflow is undefined behavior, so don't be surprised when something weird happens because of that, especially with modern compiler optimizations. For example, your entire program can be "optimized" to do absolutely nothing since it will always invoke UB. You're not even guaranteed to see the output from `std::cout<<m<<endl;`, even though the UB is invoked after that line executes.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `a.size()` is it type `size_t`, which is an unsigned int, because there wouldn’t be any reason to have a size that is negative. If you do 1-2 with unsigned numbers it will roll over and become a value near the maximum value for an unsigned int and the loop will take quite a while to run, or might not even stop since a signed integer can’t be larger than the top half of unsigned values. This depends on the rules of comparing signed and unsigned which I don’t remember for sure on the spot.

Using a debugger and making sure the types are correct (your compiler should mention signed/unsigned mismatch here) helps determine these cases.